# HTML in directive attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it a good idea to pass HTML string as a directive attribute in AngularJS? Like so:

```
<tile data-content="<b>Some text</b>"></tile>
```

This is just an example, the string would actually be much longer and more complex. I am creating tile directive that shows a modal window with additional content upon clicking.  I know it's a string like any other, but it seems to me that there's a better way.

Comment: should take a look at ng-bind-html aka ngSanitize

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [transclusion](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). With it you could do this:

```
<tile>
  <b>Some text</b>
</tile>
```

I would say this is most appropriate

Otherwise if the content is dynamic I would put it in a model and pass that to the directive. If not then I would pass an identifier for a partial html file that will be downloaded and inserted using [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service.

Answer (score 0):

if your template currently reads:

```
<span>{{dataContent}}</span>
```

change it to:

```
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="dataContent"></span>
```

Here is a fiddle  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nabeezy/HB7LU/208/) to demonstrate